# Spring boot 2.1.1 to 2.1.2: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

Migrating from spring boot 2.1.1 to 2.1.2 caused the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at br.com.xxxx.sincronizador.Sincronizador.main(Sincronizador.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurationSupport.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(WsConfigurationSupport.java:94) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dee7b281.CGLIB$payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping$8(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dee7b281$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7060e15b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dee7b281.payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Não suportado: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:574) ~[xalan-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.defaultSettings(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:53) ~[spring-xml-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.newInstance(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:32) ~[spring-xml-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.<clinit>(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping.java:58) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I use spring-ws-core (3.0.6) on a web-service subproject that is contained in the app.

I am using java 11, importing the jaxb dependencies on maven.

Any ideas why the error?

Full POM of the webservices-base:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.xxxx.webservice.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx-webservice-base</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.com.xxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--FIXME-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
            <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I use this as a base pom and each webservice use org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 to import wdsl and xsd.

Comment: Post your pom.xml. Are you using spring-boot-starter-web-services?

Comment: Posted the POM. Yes, i use spring-boot-starter-web-services. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to [SWS-1049](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-1049) recently released in 3.0.6.RELEASE. There has been a [subsequent fix](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-1050) to be more lenient.

Try setting spring-ws.version to 3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in your pom.xml, and add https://repo.spring.io/snapshot with snapshots enabled. That should clear things up.

Comment: Is there any solution which is not upgrading to SNAPSHOT version? I have faced the same issue during upgrade to Spring boot 2.1.2

Comment: @drndivoje you could try to exclude xalan from your dependencies, I did it and it worked, but obviosuly depends by your usage of xalan

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade the Spring Boot to 2.1.4 release which includes spring-ws-core

Answer (score 1):

I used the following version of spring-ws-code dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```