# Unknown attribute accessExternalDTD while creating Spring bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, saxparser

I inherited an old (15 years) Java application that was maintained badly. Mavenizing was not done proper so I did give it a try since a lot of libraries where manually added to the classpath. Now I have a master pom that have all libraries as dependency in the pom file.

The error is as below:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD

But now I have some parser issues while starting my webservices. The old project is using a SaxParser for XML but it also uses Spring where I see conflicts while initializing the beans.

I already upgraded to Java 8 (running also on Liberty Profile since we are bounded to IBM with an IBM JDK 8). Added jaxp-api to get the 'accessExternalDTD' attribute on the classpath. Removed xerces implementation (also excluded from xalan dependencies) but nothing did work.

```
[err] JAXP: find factoryId=javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
[err] JAXP: found service provider by ServiceLoader, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG CalculationExecutor:186 -    0.000 CalculationExecutor.new: begin

2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG Loader:50 - Trying to find [project-calculationKernel.xml] using context classloader: com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader@c5d35d81.

2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG Loader:56 - Found: wsjar:file:/C:/LogFiles/Tools/wlp-webProfile8-java8-win-x86_64-18.0.0.4/wlp/usr/servers/Server18.0.0.4/apps/expanded/CreditRiskWebServicesEAR.ear/CreditRiskWebServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/RiskRatingCalculation-17.0.48-SNAPSHOT.jar!/project-calculationKernel.xml

2019-01-21 11:18:35 INFO  BaseCastorMappingMarshaller:33 - Castor version used by Castor Mapping Marshaller: 1.2  [0]

2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG Loader:50 - Trying to find [castorMapping-projectConfiguration.xml] using context classloader: com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader@c5d35d81.

2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG Loader:56 - Found: wsjar:file:/C:/LogFiles/Tools/wlp-webProfile8-java8-win-x86_64-18.0.0.4/wlp/usr/servers/Server18.0.0.4/apps/expanded/CreditRiskWebServicesEAR.ear/CreditRiskWebServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/CalculationKernelSE-17.0.48-SNAPSHOT.jar!/castorMapping-projectConfiguration.xml

[err] JAXP: find factoryId=javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
[err] JAXP: found service provider by ServiceLoader, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
[err] JAXP: find factoryId=javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
[err] JAXP: found service provider by ServiceLoader, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
2019-01-21 11:18:35 DEBUG CalculationExecutor:186 -    0.00691 CalculationExecutor.new: end

[err] JAXP: find factoryId=javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
[err] JAXP: found service provider by ServiceLoader, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
[err] JAXP: find factoryId=javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
[err] Warning: external object model net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMEnvelope has been loaded, but is not an instance of net.sf.saxon.om.ExternalObjectModel
[err] Warning: external object model net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel has been loaded, but is not an instance of net.sf.saxon.om.ExternalObjectModel
[err] JAXP: found service provider by ServiceLoader, value=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapRiskApprovalService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-creditRiskWebServices.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$136.00000000124ED300.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2376)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.setConfigurationProperty(Configuration.java:2185)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:342)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.defaultSettings(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:56)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryUtils.newInstance(TransformerFactoryUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerHelper.newTransformerFactory(TransformerHelper.java:88)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerHelper.getTransformerFactory(TransformerHelper.java:104)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerHelper.createTransformer(TransformerHelper.java:119)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerHelper.transform(TransformerHelper.java:131)
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport.transform(TransformerObjectSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.getSchemaElement(InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.java:113)
    at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.addTypes(InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.java:101)
    at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition.afterPropertiesSet(ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition.java:234)
    at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultWsdl11Definition.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 15 more
```

I googled a lot but all I couldn't find any approach that would make this old application start up. Hope that someone did encounter the same issues and could point me the way how to handle this.

Comment: Take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186834/spring-boot-2-1-1-to-2-1-2-error-creating-bean-with-name-payloadrootannotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to [SWS-1049](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-1049), It was introduced in spring-ws 3.0.6.RELEASE. you need to use 3.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT instead.

Comment: Thanks, this did solve my issue. Now I have to wait for the 3.0.7.RELEASE since I am not allowed to use snapshot repositories in my config (company rules).

Comment: I am at version 3.0.8.RELEASE I can still reproduce this issue. Is there a known workaround/fix ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup *TransformerFactory* from JDK 8. Here there is an issue in JBoss, but code snapshot should work in the same way https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304023/204950

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with an old code where removing SaxonJ, or other dependencies wasn't an option.

I ended up following the [TransformerFactory::newInstance docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance--) by adding a system property to define the default TransformerFactory to instantiate:

```sh
-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

NOTE: Example is using OpenJDK8, you will have to find the `TransformerFactoryImpl` package that you want